# Avoid allowing any case for property names in .NET core rest controller

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am creating a REST controller with .NET core 2.1 using `[ApiController]` and `[FromBody]`. Suppose my parameter object is:

```
public class CreateUserParmeters
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The JSON I can send can be:

```
{ "name":"Test" }
```

But also:

```
{ "Name":"Test" }
```

Or even:

```
{ "NaMe":"Test" }
```

This will all work fine. I would like to avoid this, and only allow `name` (so camelCase). Is there a way to enforce this?

Comment: You'll probably need a custom `ContractResolver` for JSON.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this setting will help:

```
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
        {
           opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I tried this (In Startup.cs), but it does not make the deserialization case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should investigate the following [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm).

In your Global.asax:

var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

Comment: I tried this (In `Startup.cs`), but it does not make the deserialization case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define the required json attribute name using the JsonProperty attribute on the model properties.  It will serialise as you require, although it's not actually case sensitive when de-serialising json back to a model instance.

```
[JsonProperty("name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: "although it's not actually case sensitive when de-serialising json back to a model instance" -> But this is exactly my question. I want to have case sensitivity when deserializing into the model.